# Filter API array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the OpenWeather API 5 day 3 hour forecast and my response JSON is giving me 40 items in an array with "dt_txt": "2018-11-22 15:00:00" as the date format of the object. 
My problem is that I want to render one object for EACH day (15.00 everyday) and not every 3 hour. How can I filter the array to return 1 object everyday at 15.00?

My code looks like this;

```
handleFormSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch(
      "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=" +
        this.state.userInput +
        "&units=metric&APPID="
    )
      .then(results => {
        return results.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        let days = data.list
          .filter(day => {
            return day.dt_txt === **???????insert help here?????**;
          })
          .map((day, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={index}>
                <div className="card WeatherDays" style={{ paddingTop: 20 }}>
                  <p>{day.dt_txt.slice(5, 16)}</p>
                  <p style={pStyle}>{day.main.temp}°</p>
                  {day.main.temp >= 15 ? (
                    <i className="fas fa-sun icons fa-5x" />
                  ) : (
                    <i className="fas fa-cloud-sun-rain fa-5x" />
                  )}
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          });
        this.setState(() => {
          return {
            days: days,
            userInput: ""
          };
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        let errors = error;
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since dt_txt is a string , simple boolean check would suffice.

```
.filter(day => {
  return day.dt_txt.endsWith("15:00:00")
})
```